# Check if WebElement has a specific content in the :after pseudo class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium

In Selenium I've already found my element

```
IWebElement icon = box.FindElement(By.ClassName("box-icon"));
```

This element(icon) sometimes has a content set in this manner:

```
&:after {
        content: $icon-special;
    }
```

I would like to check if the `content` property is currently set to `$icon-special`. I know that I have to execute JavaScript script using `JSDriver` and pass my `IWebElement icon` to it, but I don't know how to read `after.content:` from the the JavaScript/jQuery.

I came up with that:

```
var script = @"return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').getPropertyValue('content');";
            var result = JSDriver.Execute(script, icon );
```

but the result is some weird chars like hearts, dots etc.;

**I cannot modify DOM as I am testing.**

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your actual HTML?

Comment: You can't manipulate the content of a pseudo element since it isn't a part of the DOM. You can achieve this with "toggleClass" or "hasClass, addClass, removeClass" approach...

Answer (score 1):

The return statement is missing in the script expression:

```
string script = @"return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').getPropertyValue('content');";
string result = (string)JSDriver.Execute(script, icon);
```

Comment: Yeah already found out, sorry for late update, but what i get is not a normal text but weird chars. I would expect to get:  $icon-special;  instead of "\"\""

Comment: It looks like you are getting the character code (unicode encoding) defined for the entity `$icon-special;` since it's not quoted. You could simply assert the result against the code: `result == "\uXXXX"`

Comment: Minding your explanation now it seems more reasonable : ). Can I somehow predict wat the encoding will be for certain entity? Can it change if the other styles change? Especially the last question is very important.

Comment: From your example, there's no way to tell the code. It's not a standard content keyword or HTML entity. You should check the source to find out what `$icon-special;` is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry for naive question, but how check what `$icon-special` is?

Comment: Search in the code of the page and in the code from the server.